# AngularJS - JSON and return all results

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to write a basic search function using AngularJS. I have written a service that finds my JSON file and binds it to a `$scope` object `$scope.SearchResult`

What i am trying to do it perform a search on the items within `SearchResult` when the user enters a string. For any matches found,return the entire contents.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>


<input ng-model="searchText">
<button ng-click="performSearch(searchText)">Submit</button>

{{ item }}


</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';

$scope.SearchResult = [
{
     "Index":1,
     "Title":"Help",
     "Snippet":"You found Mr Happy",
     "Url":"www.test.co.uk"
  },
  {
     "Index":2,
     "Title":"Conatct",
     "Snippet":"You found Mr Happy",
     "Url":"www.test.co.uk"
  },
  {
     "Index":3,
     "Title":"Help",
     "Snippet":"You found Mrs Angry",
     "Url":"www.test.co.uk"
  },
  {
     "Index":4,
     "Title":"Help",
     "Snippet":"You found Mr Sad",
     "Url":"www.test.co.uk"
  }
];

    $scope.performSearch = function(searchText) {

        console.log("Performing a search....");

        angular.forEach($scope.SearchResult.Snippet, function(item) {
            if( item.label.indexOf(searchText) >= 0 ) filtered.push(item);
            console.log(item);
        });

    }  

});
```

So if HAPPY was entered in the input field, 2 matches would be found and displayed.

Heres a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mOjcYUbFpoveaDw12NjE?p=preview

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @user256103 - the results are not showing.

Comment: numerous problems here, there is no array `$scope.SearchResult.Snippet` , nothing has a property `label` and `filtered` is undefined

Comment: Something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/xSVrG95OGZRTVyn4KYPF?p=preview

Comment: @pixelbits - Hi, that is very close. I copied your code to my application, but on click of search i am seeing: ReferenceError: $filter is not defined

Comment: Fixed the above by adding $filter to my controller